# How to create a home network over a wide area

Tags: networking, home-networking, ethernet, switch

I am trying to design a flexible and "future-ready" home network for our 3-story, 5-room townhouse, with a 4-port ethernet wall plate in each room, using one of the ports in each room as an input and the other 3 as outputs.  This would give us, and future inhabitants, the flexibility to plug the source from the modem/router in from any of the five rooms.

However, all of the ethernet switches I've seen so far have only one input, rendering my otherwise practical idea next to impossible, without manually splicing cables together, which would no doubt take the Big Gs out of bit rate of the cat. 6(a) that I was planning on using.

Comment: can you provide an example of a product you looked at because I find it odd your finding switches with only a single input.

Comment: Could you add a diagram of how you are planning to connect the rooms? It sounds like you are trying to create a mesh topology (connect every room to every other room), I would not recommend that for small networks.

Comment: He probably talks about the link port which is used to link 2 switches together to do load balancing, or researched hubs rather than switches. Old hubs had a button to change one output port to an uplink port to connect it to another hub or switch.

Comment: Btw, upon making physical splice into cat5, cat5e, cat6, cat6a UTP (unshielded twisted pair), the cable no longer meets the spec.  I'm not saying it won't work (insomuch as silently screaming it), as such statements invite folksy anecdotes of how someone's uncle was able to get the back 50 online by using the strands of barbed wire, but it's um, not recommended.

Answer (score 4):

Keep it simple - 4 ethernet cables from each room to a [patch panel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_panel) - switch connections at the patch panel to convert a port from an input or output port there. You can then make the connections from the patch panel to the router. An ethernet cable is an ethernet cable, and its simpler to just change what its plugged into on the other end.

Comment: For added superiority one could add wifi bridges/boosters around the home to increase connectivity everyone and with everything.

Answer (score 0):

I do this and I simply use 1 router and a few switches (if needed) and powerline adapters. It's really simple.

You plug 1 Ethernet from the router into a powerline adapter, which plugs into the mains. You can then use the mains to move the connection around the house.

Each room uses a normal mains plug socket for another powerline adapter and from there it plugs either into a [4 port switch](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=4+port+switch&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=nHZzU7ShHaSUigbdroD4CQ) (to give me the extra ports) or direct into the device (computer/music player/media streaming device etc)

The room with the switch has 2 NAS drives so I can also stream my music/video.

You can also (as I did) add a router to one of the powerlines, and set it up as an access point thus expanding your wireless coverage.

Naturally, this only works if the house's mains wiring is all connected! If you have different and independent circuits, the it won't work